# How to properly configure the .htaccess of Typo3 to run realurl

Tags: mod-rewrite, typo3, realurl

I'm a newcomer to typo3 and my current task is to get realurl working. After studying many tutorials and the official documentation I got realurl to the point that the links are converted correctly as expected.

The problem I don't get solved even after testing multiple solutions is the wrong behaviour of the apache server (configured via .htaccess, mod_rewrite). It correctly ignores the rewrites to uploads/ fileadmin / typo3conf but never rewrites the url to index.php when it comes to typo-pages.

Here is the corresponding .htaccess entry:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^uploads/.*$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^fileadmin/.*$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^typo3conf/.*$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
    RewriteRule / %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.htm -f
    RewriteRule / %{REQUEST_URI}/index.htm [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
    RewriteRule / %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule * /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Does anybody have an idea whats wrong with this configuration? I'm some kind of desperate :(

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Give the versions of TYPO3 and Apache, also check if __mod_rewrite__ is enabled via `phpinfo()`. Actually ignoring paths from rewriting looks identically like not enabled  `mod_rewrite` - it just does nothing.

Comment: Just a wild guess: url rewriting is not supported by your server. Probably mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Best solved with a rewrite log: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog